# Browser Viewport is different from Chrome to Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, next.js, safari

I open the same page on Safari and on Chrome.

On Safari the width of the content is 1440px:
[image]

On Chrome width is 1600px:
[image]

there is no zoom, it is "actual size"
I tried to add 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

But it didn't help. 
What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your windows are the same width? I have never seen this as sn issue before and the discrepancy is too large, yet both values seem like normal screen widths…

Comment: Have you looked at the resultant CSS and HTML and could you show us that code so we can witness the problem. Are you certain your browser devtools are set up the same way?

Comment: @AHaworth it is a big project. I am not sure what part of CSS is doing that

Comment: @somethinghere it is the same device. MacBook 13’. Dev tools on bottom so I see the full width of screen